# User input into a string Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to enter user input into a string in two places in python 2.7.12
I want it to look something like this

```
    import os
    1 = input()
    2 = input()
    print os.listdir("/home/test/1/2")
```

I know you can use .format() to input into string but the only way I know how to do it is

```
    print os.listdir("/home/test/{0}".format(1))
```

but I couldn't figure out how to enter a second input into the string.
sorry for any confusion, I'm kinda new to Stack Overflow. If you have any questions please ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os
segment1 = input()
segment2 = input()
print os.listdir("/home/test/{}/{}".format(segment1, segment2))
```

`1` and `2` are not legal variable names, so `1 = input()` will cause an error.

You can use as many variables as you want in your format string; just pass them as additional parameters to `.format(...)`. In the format string, you can use `{0}`, `{1}`, etc., or you can just use `{}` positionally. (The first `{}` refers to the first parameter, the second `{}` to the second parameter, etc.).